# How many morphemes are in a contraction?

Tags: morphemes

I'm a little bit confused about how to count morphemes when we talk about contractions such as "I'm" or "don't". I need to calculate the ratio of morphemes to words.

Comment: Two morphemes in each, the ones that differ from their standalone variants are allomorphs, e.g. _'m_ is an allomorph of _am_, a clitic form thereof.

Comment: 3 is quite common in English - _Shouldn't've_ or _shouldna_, likewise _wouldna, couldna,, oughtna,_. And then there's _Whatcha_, with 3, though not always the some 3: _What do you_ or _What are you_.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to have a theory of morphemes, whereby you can answer the question "how many morphemes are there in *do, does, did, is, am*?". If you think that "am" has two morphemes, then "do" probably does as well, which can affect your count of morphemes in *don't*. In a writing-based analysis, you would not notice that the root of *do* is different from the root of *don't*. Most contemporary theories of morphosyntax have numerous phonologically empty or nearly-empty morphemes, corresponding to agreement features. So it ultimately depends on why you are counting morphemes, rather than counting something else. Also incidentally, you have to have a theory that tells you that "I'm" is one word and not two.